# css: table-less layout for comments

Tags: css, layout, comments

I am clueless on table-less layout in CSS and want to convert a simple comment system that lays out the comments with tables to a simple one in CSS.  Here is what it looks like with tables.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="headshot.gif" width=40 border-0>
        </td>
        <td><span style="font-color:gold;font-weight:bold;">Kumar</span>
            <br>I really liked the movie - 3 days ago</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone suggest right way to go about this with table-less layout.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SfeMs/

```
div .img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div .text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Colors and widths are unimportant. Just make a few inline-block spans.

Comment: Question is how to get the image in one "cell" and the text in a separate one to the right so that the text does not wrap around image and it displays neatly as in typical comment layout.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. I guess I didn't understand the question.

Comment: I imagine you create spans and then style them in css with tags like float and offset but I'm clueless on how to do this.

Comment: what would I use instead?

Comment: What I put up there. Just make two spans and set their display to `inline-block`. They will sit next to each other regardless of height. There are other ways to do this depending on other factors, heights of elements, flexibility required, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer from here:
[Make two parallel `<div>` colums the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592058/make-two-parallel-div-colums-the-same-height/20592204#20592204)
You can use one "column" for image and the other one for text

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help with an example of what I have found that works in the past. Let's start with the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul id="regis_ul">
        <li id="regis_li">
            <label><span> Username: </span>
 <span><input type = 'text' name ='username' id ='username' value = ></span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li id="regis_li">
            <label> <span> Password: </span>
    <span><input type = 'password' name ='password' id ='password' value ='' ></span>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li id="regis_li">
            <label> <span> Retype Password: </span>
    <span><input type = 'password' name ='repassword' id ='repassword' value ='' ></span>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li id="regis_li">
            <label> <span> Email Address: </span>
    <span><input type = 'text' name ='email' id ='email' value ='' ></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
</form>
</div>
```

This just sets up a simple, box like, structured system that allows for a registration to a page, but can easily be restructured to become something used for comments. Now here is the key part, the CSS which initially designs everything:

```
#regis_ul {
    display:table;
}
#regis_li {
    display:table-row-group;
}
#sub_but {
    margin-left: 0 auto;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
}
label {
    display: table-row;
}
```

One key thing to note in this aspect is the display choices used in many of the CSS elements here. More, exact information can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) along with many other tricks that can be used in CSS. To provide a little more information, this display method "tricks" the browser into thinking it is a table and to display it like one. What is the difference between using a table and an unordered list? All of that information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html), where a list of pros and cons is gone over.

Now you're probably wondering what this actually looks like, well I have provided a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma93j/) with the exact representation.

So What do you do now? Well.. I encourage you to play with the code I have provided, it will help you to find the exact thing layout you want for your comment system. A few things to note that you will end up needing.. a div, which actually holds the entire set of elements inside of it (like a safety precaution to make sure all of the information stays in on box) and then an unordered list to create a structured flow...

Lastly, I do want to mention that you can easily implement MySQL and PHP with this comment system but if you don't know what that is, then don't even worry about it :). I encourage you to explore and play with my example and also to look over more information on cool things in CSS with the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com).

Good luck on your future coding projects, I hope it all works well for you :)